Restricting geodatabase editing in QGIS
I'm working on a project using QGIS. I want to allow my colleagues to view the geodatabase without giving them edit permissions. Does anyone know how I can block editing while still allowing the data to be visualized?

To stop editing completely you can make a copy and make it read-only. But you would need to make sure the files are keep in sync. It would be better if the data was in a database (like postgres) and you can lock down access with user/role privileges.

Or grant them read-only access to the relevant folders.

Thank you @Mapperz

A not really safe (because user would be able to re-allow editing) but quite simple solution is to set the layer as read-only in the project properties : go to Project>Properties... select the data source tab and tick the appropriate box.

This solution is only good to prevent user from editing by mistake, if you really need to prevent edit even by knowledgeable user the best solution is the suggestion by @Mapperz to use a proper database where you could properly manage edit permission (or put the data file as read-only but that would prevent anyone to edit...)

Thank you soo much... Will try both methods.
